# Right way of performing sliding windows in Pandas:

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, sliding-window

I'm trying to calculate the variance of a sliding window in a pandas DataFrame. The following line, however, returns 'Incompatible indexer with Series'. Each side of the assignment works individually (setting i to a constant):

1. What is wrong with this statement?
2. Is this the most efficient for a sliding window calculation using Pandas? I noticed that using two for-loops using .iloc makes it impossibly slow.

   ```
   for i in train.index[168:]:
       train.loc[i,'Var'] = train.loc[i - pd.Timedelta('7 Days'): i].var()
   ```

Comment: `pd.rolling` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Comment: In case, can you clarify what is wrong with my loop as well?